# In the first steps of app design, what should go first: UML class diagrams or the GUI mockup?

Tags: user-interface, uml

I'm wondering whether I should design first a mockup of the user interface, and then create the classes, or whether I should adapt the mockup to the classess I previously created through the UML class diagram.

Answer (score 0):

GUI mockup is not software design and UML class diagram construction is.  Since the GUI review helps refine the app requirements, that should be done as early as possible.  However, usually enough is known about what the app is supposed to do to begin work on the domain chart and class diagrams in parallel with the GUI.  You should strive for decoupling the GUI from the rest of the application (see the model, view, controller pattern).  That said, when users start to play with the GUI, you will find functionality that needs to be added, modified, or deleted.  If you are working alone, my advice would be to get something into the hands of the users early and then work on the design (class diagrams) while they are trying it out.  If you are doing prototype coding for your GUI, try a preliminary class diagram for the back end.  The best way is to have a graphic designer doing the GUI and the software engineer doing the software architecture.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to show on your class diagram?

If it is on the conceptual level (in contrast to implementation - design level) you could do both modelling in parallel. As you progress with the identification of your domain objects you mock-up the UI and vice versa. It is important to keep both models consistent - UI elements should be clearly traceable to class diagram features.

Later in your process you could derive a design level class diagram from the conceptual one and add the implementation details - programming languages, precise methods, types, etc. This modelling will probably happen after mock-up and even use mock-up as an input.

If your problem is simple enough, you can consider making only one level of class modelling and even finish it completely before or after mock-up.

All options are open, listen to your developer instinct and make the model which would best assist you through your development process. The ultimate aim is to make a software product of quality and the modelling technique is flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Mock UI first , followed by usecase/activity/sequence diagrams and then class diagrams.